# how multiply two dimensional array aka matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, dimensional

I want to know how to multiply 2D arrays (matrices) and show them as a matrix.

The current output is

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

which is not the correct result.

The code is below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] metrix1 = new int[3, 3] { { 2, 0, 2 }, { 0, 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 1 } };
        int[,] metrix2 = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 } };
        int[,] result = new int[3, 3];

        int m1 =0;
        int m2 =0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                m1 = metrix1[i, j];

            }
        }

        // metrix 2
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                {
                    m2 = metrix2[y, z];
                }
            }
            //m

                for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                    {

                        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
                        {
                        result[a, b] = m1 *m2;
                        Console.Write(result[a, b] );

                        }Console.WriteLine();
                }Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use only two for loops

Comment: `result[a, b] = m1 *m2;` is setting every `result` element to whatever is in `m1` times whatever is in `m2`. `m1` and `m2` are both `1` because that is the very last element in both of your arrays. Look at your code at the line `//m`, at this point in your code you've run two sets of double `for` loops to completion, and the last iteration of the first set assigned `1` to `m1`, and the last iteration of the second set assigned `1` to `m2`, then you go through and assign `1*1` to every element of `result`. P.s., please use proper spelling and grammar when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this incorrectly.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
            {
                m2 = metrix2[y, z];
            }
        }
```

After this, m2 will contain the lower right-hand value of the array (`matrix[2, 2]`). You're literally multiplying the same value over and over again for your multiplication. You need to put all of this in one `for` loop.

Also, that's not the correct way to do matrix multiplication. To begin with, your code will only work for a 3x3 matrix; not only can you have other sizes of matrices (4x4, 5x5, etc.), matrices don't even have to be square to be able to multiply them (as long as the number of columns of one equals the number of rows of the other). Even if they *are* both 3x3 matrices, the calculation would still be wrong. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) has some good examples of the proper way to do this.

```
2 0 2   1 1 1   (2*1)+(0*0)+(2*0)  (2*1)+(0*1)+(2*0) ...  
0 1 2 x 0 1 0 = (0*1)+(1*0)+(2*0)  (0*1)(1*1)(2*0) ...
1 2 1   0 0 1   ..
```